# Constantly Updating Variable

Tags: android, delay

I am writing a program that will be constantly receiving data via usb.  I want to be able to take this value and display it in a TextView that updates every quarter second.  I have experimented with a postDelayed handler, but the value only updates once my variable has stopped changing.  (I have been testing this with just an incrementing for loop and outputting the value of the loop)  I have also tried using `Thread.sleep(250)` inside of my loop but this doesn't work either.  So basically I want to know how to update a TextView every quarter second.

Comment: Did you call `invalidate()` after changing the textview?

Comment: I did not until now.  After adding it, it still behaves the same way.  (Updates at the end of the loop).  Within my loop I called: `tv.setText(x+"");
 tv.invalidate();`

Comment: postDelayed() is a single shot posting... if the runnable you post also calls postDelayed() then you can establish an update repetition. As to only updating once your variable stops changing... is it changing inside your UI thread? If so, stop that! Give it its own thread to process in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a periodic timer of some sort (several are available) which will fire every 250ms. Since this timer will (presumably) run in a different thread than your main UI thread, and since only the UI thread is permitted to modify your TextView, your timer callback will call `runOnUiThread(runnable);` when it triggers. Your runnable will update the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler mUpdater = new Handler();
Runnable mUpdateView = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
   tv.setText(newText);
   tv.invalidate();
   mUpdater.postDelayed(this, updateIntervalInMilliSeconds);
 }
}
```

This will automatically update the TextView with whatever `newText` is at the time of the update.  It will update every `updateIntervalInMilliSeconds`.  Just call `mUpdateView.run()` to start it.  Make sure you end it in `onPause()` with `mUpdater.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` to stop the updating.

You can also stop it by setting a boolean that is checked within the run.  You can also start it at a delay by calling `mUpdater.postDelayed(mUpdateView, updateInMilliseconds);`.

Either way, the `postDelayed` is a one-time execute and you have to keep calling it in order to auto-update.

Answer (score 0):

You should have method for recieving data from USB. Put the code for updating your `TextView` in this method.

For example:

```
public void getDataFromUsb(String data){ // or whatever it is you are getting from USB

yourTextView.setText(data);

}
```

this code will refresh your `TextView` with new value every time you get data from USB.